# Infragistics UltraGrid: How to force a CellUpdate event after user selects from drop down

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Infragistics UltraGrid: Column has a drop down with auto-complete. How can I force a CellUpdate when the user selects an item from the list and not have to wait for him to hit enter or click a different cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And, the answer is:

```
grid.AfterCellListCloseUp += delegate { grid.UpdateData(); };
```

Much thanks to Mike Saltzman, the Infragistics Grid Guru:

http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/47347/253023.aspx#253023

Answer (score 1):

similar post was submitted to Infragistics forums and was answered.

http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/47347/253023.aspx#253023

Thanks.

Comment: Thats very perceptive, but it was not successfully answered yet. I need to find an event for selectionchangecommitted on the grid and then j can call update. What is that event?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this (in VB.NET) is to declare the dropdown:

```
Private WithEvents dd As New UltraDropDown
```

Then set the `DataSource`, `ValueMember`, `DisplayMember`, etc.

Then set the `ValueList` property of your column to the dropdown:

```
Me.ultragrid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("Name").ValueList = dd
```

Then on the `RowSelected` event of the dropdown, call the `Update()` method for the `ActiveRow` of the UltraGrid:

```
Me.ultragrid.ActiveRow.Update()
```

Comment: Me.ultragrid.ActiveRow.Update()  Works fine for me